# How to use multiple bundle paths in Ruby on Rails (bundler)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm using a few gems for interactivity with my database and to provide easy pagination. After deploying my application on my server, it'll automatically execute `bundle install` to install those gems if they aren't installed yet. This is helpful when I deploy a codebase update including a new gem.

However, there's one gem (will_paginate) I've made a little change to (so that it always shows on what page you are, no matter the total number of pages).

Therefore, I used `bundle install --local --path vendor` at my local machine (OS X Lion) so that I can easily edit them (at per-app base, instead of system-wide).

Because of dependency problems, I cannot 'just' copy the vendor-folder to my web server. Therefore, I decided to add another rule to my `.gitignore`-file:

```
vendor
```

Because this caused my customized `will_paginate`-gem not to get uploaded, I executed another command:

```
git add -f vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/will_paginate
```

Now, when I push, the only gem in the vendor folder at my web server is `will_paginate`, which is great.

However, it doesn't get loaded, since it isn't in the bundle path.

---

I already tried to create a file called `.bundle/config` and add the following in it:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor
```

I also tried adding `BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "0"`, but using this, `bundle check` says it's missing the shared gems.

---

My question is, how can I add a bundle path `vendor`, and fallback on the system-wide `gem`-path.

Comment: Any reason you're not just forking the gem in github and point your gemfile to the forked repository?

Comment: Well, it differs just one line, so I didn't think that would be worth it. But on the other hand, I'm just giving it a try now =)!

Comment: +1 for Beerlington's idea. Also, I wonder if you might be able to override the relevant will_paginate method by monkey patching.